# Managing comments in Ableton Live

Tags: vst, ableton-live

Looking for a method to add and manage comments in my composition. 
I'm familiar with adding a marker text, edit info view text, and insert text to lesson file techniques.

Tried quite many VST but neither works in Live 9 (both 64 and 32 with jBridge),
the exception is Max For Live "Notepad 1.0" which does work, but has a very basic functionality:  
http://www.maxforlive.com/library/device.php?id=176

**Was hoping to find a VST with more advanced features**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yet another for SD please Tim..